# Laravel Mockery - This test did not perform any assertions

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I am trying to create a mockery unit test but it giving me this error

This test did not perform any assertions

```
public function testGetById()
{
    $mock = Mockery::mock(PostService::class)->makePartial();
    $mock->shouldReceive('getById')
        ->withSomeOfArgs(1);
        $mock->getById(1);
}
```

> ! get by id→ This test did not perform any assertions
> \tests\Unit\PostControllerTest.php:30
>
> Tests:  1 risked   Time:   0.32s Warning: TTY mode is not supported
> on Windows platform.

Comment: you should add assertion to your unit test, something like:
$this->assertEqual( ...

Comment: Wich type of assertion I should use ?

Comment: Can you give me example

Answer (score 4):

There are two options.

Option 1:

- make sure you have added a tearDown method with `Mockery::close();
- then use any assertion.
- If you don't really need one, use `$this->assertTrue(true);`

Option 2:

You can also extend `Mockery\Adapter\Phpunit\MockeryTestCase` instead of the usual `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`. That way you don't have to add phpunit assertions at all.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry that I cannot help you 100%, I cannot setup a testing project right now to try this, but you can try it:

```php
public function testGetById()
{
    $mock = Mockery::spy(PostService::class);
    // Bind the mock to the Service Container so it gets injected (DI)

    // Execute the code that would run that mock
    $mock->shouldHaveReceived('getById')
        ->withSomeOfArgs(1);
}
```

Spies allow you to *spy* if the desired method got called with desired conditions. If you `mock`, you are just "faking" what it will return or do, if you `spy`, you will be able to *assert* what happened to a method.

Read more about it on the [official Mockery documentation](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/spies.html).